# XPath selecting the node right after the criteria matching node

Tags: python, xpath

am trying to use XPATH to extract data from XHTML files, I have a scenario where I want  to a match a TD element and then get the TD right after it.

Here is the HTML sample

```
  <tr> 
     <td colspan="3" style="border-top:1px solid rgb(234,234,234);padding:0pt 0pt 16px;width:560px">   </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td colspan="2" style="font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;padding:0 10px 0 0;color:rgb(51,51,51);width:480px" align="right" valign="top"> Item Subtotal: </td> 
     <td style="font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;color:rgb(51,51,51);width:80px" align="right" valign="top"> $25.79 </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td colspan="2" style="font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;padding:0 10px 0 0;color:rgb(51,51,51);width:480px" align="right" valign="top"> Shipping &amp; Handling: </td> 
     <td style="font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;color:rgb(51,51,51);width:80px" align="right" valign="top"> $0.00 </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td colspan="2" style="font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;padding:0 10px 0 0;color:rgb(51,51,51);width:480px" align="right" valign="top"> Total Before Tax: </td> 
     <td style="font:12px/18px Arial,sans-serif;color:rgb(51,51,51);width:80px" align="right" valign="top"> $25.79 </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td colspan="2" style="font:14px Arial,sans-serif;padding:10px 10px 10px 0;color:#333;width:480px" align="right" valign="top"> Shipment Total: </td> 
     <td style="color:#333;font:14px Arial,sans-serif;padding:10px 0 5px 0;color:#333;width:80px" align="right" valign="top"> <b> $25.79 </b> </td> 
    </tr>
```

What am trying to do is, get the TD element with has "Shipment Total" and then extract the value from the TD element right after it. I managed to select the element using XPATH but cannot find a way to jump to the next element

```
xhtml = etree.HTML(i.get('content').encode('utf8'))
result = etree.tostring(xhtml, pretty_print=True, method="html")
root = html.fromstring(result)
print root.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "Shipment Total:")]')
```

Its easier todo that in BeautifulSoup but am restricted with XPath, anyone can help if this would be possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the TD immediately after the TD you've selected you might be interested in this XPath expression:

```
//td[contains(text(), "Shipment Total:")]/following-sibling::td
```